# Prove that the normal closure of $S \subset G $ is equal to $\langle s^g \mid s\in S, g\in G \rangle.$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

How can I prove that the normal closure of $S \subset G $ is equal to $\langle s^g \mid s\in S, g\in G \rangle$?

Comment: Isn't this the definition of the normal closure of $S?$

Comment: The way our professor defined normal closure is the intersection of all normal subgroups of $G$ containing $S$, i.e. the smallest normal subgroup containin $S$.

Comment: @W.Scott Any normal subgroup containing $S$ contains $s^g$ for all $s\in S$, and $g\in G$, hence will contain the subgroup generated by such elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The normal closure of a subset $S$ of a group $G$ is the smallest
normal subgroup of $G$ containing $S$. Let's call it $K$. Each $s\in S$
lies in $K$ and as $K$ is normal, it contains the conjugates of all its
elements, so $s^g\in K$ for all $s\in S$, $g\in G$. As
$\langle s^g:s\in S,g\in G\rangle$
is the smallest subgroup of $G$ containing
all these $s^g$, it is a subgroup of $K$.

But $\langle s^g:s\in S,g\in G\rangle$ is a normal subgroup
of $G$ as $\{ s^g:s\in S,g\in G\}$ is stable under all conjugations
of $G$, the group it generates also is. So $\langle s^g:s\in S,g\in G\rangle$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ which contains $S$. Therefore
$\langle s^g:s\in S,g\in G\rangle\supseteq K$. So
$\langle s^g:s\in S,g\in G\rangle=K$.

Comment: Why does the stability of a set $S$ under all conjugations imply the stability of $\langle S\rangle$ under all conjugations?

Comment: You claim that $\{s^g  : s \in S, g\in G \}$ being stable under conjugations implies that the group it generates is also stable under conjugations. Why is that?

Comment: Oh, never mind. Found the answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2484189/369800

Comment: For reference for others: $S \subseteq G$ implies $g^{-1} \langle S \rangle g = \langle g^{-1} S g \rangle$ for any $g \in G$.