# Let $G$ be a group, $S\subseteq G$ and $g\in G$ , then $g \left \langle S \right \rangle g^{-1}= \left \langle g S g^{-1}\right \rangle $

Tags: group-theory

> Let $G$ be a group, $S\subseteq G$ and $g\in G$
>   , then $g \left \langle  S \right \rangle g^{-1}=
> \left \langle g \mathcal S g^{-1}\right \rangle $

This is a homework question but why there is this curly $\mathcal S$ instead of S. What does that mean? And is any hint suggested?

Comment: More generally, given any homomorphism $f:G\to H$, we have $f(\langle S\rangle)=\langle f(S)\rangle$. This is the special case with $H=G$ and $f(x)=gxg^{-1}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Span}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}$Let $T \subseteq G$ and $h \in G$. Since $T \subseteq \Span{T}$, we have $h T h^{-1} \subseteq h \Span{T} h^{-1}$, so that
$$
\Span{h T h^{-1}} \subseteq h \Span{T} h^{-1}.
$$
Now use this twice, first with $T = S$ and $h = g$, to get
$$
\Span{g S g^{-1}} \subseteq g \Span{S} g^{-1},
$$
and then with $T = g S g^{-1}$ and $h = g^{-1}$ to get
$$
\Span{S} \subseteq g^{-1} \Span{g S g^{-1}} g,
$$
whence
$$
g \Span{S} g^{-1} \subseteq  \Span{g S g^{-1}}.
$$

Comment: How did you get here : $
\Span{h T h^{-1}} \subseteq h \Span{T} h^{-1}.
$ @Andreas Caranti

Comment: @LeylaAlkan $\newcommand{\Span}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}$$\Span{S}$ is defined as the smallest subgroup containing $S$. In other words, for every $H \le G$, the following are equivalent: (1) $S \le H$; (2) $\Span{S} \le H$. Therefore $h T h^{-1} \subseteq h \Span{T} h^{-1}$ implies $\Span{h T h^{-1}} \subseteq h \Span{T} h^{-1}$.

Answer (score 5):

The curly $S$ is a typo, I guess.

**Hint:** Prove that $g\langle S\rangle g^{-1}\subset\langle gSg^{-1}\rangle$ and that $g\langle S\rangle g^{-1}\supset\langle gSg^{-1}\rangle$. Also, use the fact that $(gag^{-1})^{-1}=ga^{-1}g^{-1}$.