# Let $G$ be a group and $S \subset G$. How can I show that the normal closure of $S$ in $G$ is equal to $\langle gsg^{-1}\mid g\in G,s\in S\rangle$?

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

Let $G$ be a group and $S \subset G$. How can I show that the normal closure of $S$ in $G$ is equal to $\langle gsg^{-1} \mid g \in G, s \in S \rangle$?

It is worth remembering that the normal closure of $S$ in $G$ is the smallest normal subgroup of $G$ that contains $S.$

I know that I must show that the generated is a subgroup of $G$, normal in $G$. Thus, to conclude that the normal closure is equal to the generated. Assuming that $K$ is the normal closure, then $K$ is equal to the generated one. As I said, my difficulty is the algebraic manipulations

Comment: Yes, so show first that $\langle gsg^{-1} \mid g \in G,s \in S \rangle$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, and then show that it is contained in any normal subgroup of $G$ that contains $S$. Both are straightforward.

Comment: Well what have you done? Is it a subroup? does it contain $S$? is it normal? Does it lie in any normal subgroup containing $S$? Surely you've done some of these?

Comment: My difficulty is in algebraic manipulations.

Comment: Your last comment should be part of the question, not a comment. Please edit your question and include your thoughts on how to solve the problem. Otherwise the question will probably be closed.

Comment: Duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2269423/104041

Comment: I didn't understand that Shaun

Comment: What's the first thing about it you don't understand, @Mathtask?

Comment: Algebraic manipulations. I would like to know algebraically the equality showing the salutes

Comment: Assuming that K is the normal close. How to complete the salutes, that is, K is contained in the generated and the generated is contained in K?

Comment: What do you mean by "salutes"?

Comment: It's okay not to get it right away. Give it time.